# Rails Braintree gem subscription class conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subscription, braintree

In my Rails app, I'm using the Braintree gem to create subscriptions.  Without realizing, I had also created a Subscription model and controller to manage the subscription info I wanted to store locally.  In my model, a subscription can belong_to a user.  However, some of the normal stuff you can do wasn't working such as 
    current_user.subscriptions.build()

But for some reason when someone was helping me they were able to use

```
current_user.create_subscription
```

Where is this create_subscription method defined?  Is it somehow overriding the Rails convention?

I noticed that there is a subscription.rb file in the Braintree gem.  Is there some conflict with the class defined by Braintree and my Subscription model?  I know that I can probably just rename my Subscription model, but I'm curious as to what the conflict is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the subscription relation is has_one or belongs_to, rather than has_many.  User would not have a subscriptions method in this case as the attached subscription would be singular.  Review the API docs for how to manipulate these sorts of relations in AR.

From the manual on has_one:

```
The following methods for retrieval and query of a single associated object will be added:

association(force_reload = false)

Returns the associated object. nil is returned if none is found.

association=(associate)

Assigns the associate object, extracts the primary key, sets it as the foreign key, and saves the associate object.

build_association(attributes = {})

Returns a new object of the associated type that has been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but has not yet been saved. Note: This ONLY works if an association already exists. It will NOT work if the association is nil.

create_association(attributes = {})

Returns a new object of the associated type that has been instantiated with attributes, linked to this object through a foreign key, and that has already been saved (if it passed the validation).
```

Braintree does have a Subscription class, but this is namespaced to Braintree:Subscription so it is not the issue.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Didn't know it was different with has_one.  Thank you!